# How to set hyperlink for first column cell from value of second column cell

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using generated table and need for first column cells to have hyperlinks that ar in second column. Is it achievable with JavaScript?

```js
$('table .one').each(function() {
  var a1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var a2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
  $(this).innerHtml = '<a href="' + a2 + '">' + a1 + '</a>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">text1</td>
      <td class="two">link1.com</td>
      <td class="three"> text13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">text2</td>
      <td class="two">link2.com</td>
      <td class="three">text23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi there Edmis, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Since this is your first post I want to offer some advice. You will probably have better luck if you can post an example of HTML and Javascript samples that you have tried. That will allow someone to provide a solution for that specific example. Good luck and happy learning!

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example But just-to say, yes it is possible to do what you need probably, we need example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `.html()` like below:

```js
$('table .one').each(function() {
  var a1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var a2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
  $(this).html('<a href="' + a2 + '">' + a1 + '</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">text1</td>
      <td class="two">link1.com</td>
      <td class="three"> text13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">text2</td>
      <td class="two">link2.com</td>
      <td class="three">text23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```